# how to add class to a listitem from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am dynamically generating paging from code behind but my html design is different. How to add a class to listitem. The code is as below

```
 if (pageCount > 0)
    {
        pages.Add(new ListItem("First", "1", currentPage > 1));
        for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++)
        {
            pages.Add(new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString(), i != currentPage));
        }
        pages.Add(new ListItem("Last", recordCount.ToString(), currentPage < pageCount));
    }
```

Html for the same is

```
 <ul class="pages-pagina">
<li class="pages previous"><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
<li class="pages selected"><a href="#">1</a></li>
<li class="pages"><a href="#">2</a></li>
<li class="pages"><a href="#">3</a></li>
<li class="pages"><a href="#">4</a></li>
<li class="pages"><a href="#">5</a></li>
<li>...</li>
<li class="pages last"><a href="#">10</a></li>
<li class="pages next"><a href="#">Next</a></li>


</ul>
```

Thanks,

Comment: what kind of class and where to add it? please give a sample of the final HTML with the class

Comment: As you can see in the html provided the Previous is the link for the listitem mentioned first and Next is the link for the listitem mentioned Last.

Comment: Currently i am getting First 1 2 Last. I want Previous 1 2 Next as shown in the html.

Comment: Your question isn't still enough clear. You need also to change the functionality, so that next moves to the next page and last to the last? Please, clarify it editing your question, not adding comments, so that othe rpeople can understand you.

Answer (score 3):

Use Attributes.Add of ListItem Object.

```
ListItem li = new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString(), i != currentPage);
li.Attributes.Add("class", "pages");
```

pages.Add(li);